# Restrict main.bundle.js to directly access from browser in angular 4 application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iis

I have deployed a angular site in IIS

> Its works fine.

But there are some javascipt files like

```
main.bundle.js
inline.bundle.js
polyfills.bundle.js
```

So on..

directly accessible like below:

> http://localhost/main.bundle.js

How i can prevent this accessing directly in browser?

I turned off directory browsing in IIS and didnt help much.

If it not turned off this is a serious security issue.

please help

Comment: They have to be accessible by the browser for your site to work properly

Comment: it contains payloads and return data from api which is a serious security issue.

Comment: Also all logics are directly available to public

Comment: These bundles are always publicly available because that's executed on the clients. You should therefore never include sensitive data in these files.